# Calling a javascript function in node.js via Unity3D?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unity-game-engine

Unity WebGL has a method for calling javascript functions from jslib however I need to integrate those function calls to node.js in order to use firebase.

What I tried to do is as follows:

```
// entry.js:
require("./style.css");
document.write(require("./content.js"));

require('./UnityLoader.js');

var firebase = require('firebase');

function foo() {
    window.alert("ENTRY HELLOW WORLD");
}


wvar gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Build/WebGLNodeContainer.json");
document.write('<div id="gameContainer" style="width: 960px; height: 600px; margin: auto"></div>');
```

Then from inside Unity I tried to do an external call like so:

```
public class FirebaseWebGL : IFirebaseLib
    {
        [DllImport("__Internal")]
        private static extern void foo();

        public void Login(string username, string password)
        {
              foo();
        }
    }
```

I'm not too surprised this didn't work, while [Unity's docs claim you can call javascript in your webpage](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) the instructions they give involves packaging in the javascript files into your Unity project which doesn't play nice with node.js/webpack.

Is there a way around this? My main goal is to prompt a firebase login and grab the auth token from it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send an HTTP request to the Node.JS server either from the C# or via an AJAX call from a js function.

You cannot directly invoke a Node.js function because Node itself is a separate server - different from the one hosting your game/experience.